# char counter doesn't work with paste event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jscript

I have written a code bellow for counting the character inside text box.
the code is working just fine the only problem with it is when i past a text into the text box i have to press any key so system start to count.

Could you please help me sort this problem

```
function GetAlhpa(text) {
    var gsm = "@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞ^{}\[~]|€ÆæßÉ!\"#¤%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà";
    var i = 0;
    while (i <= String(text).length) {
        if (gsm.indexOf(String(String(text).charAt(i))) == -1 && (String(text).charCodeAt(i) != 32) && (String(text).charCodeAt(i) != 27) && (String(text).charCodeAt(i) != 10) && (String(text).charCodeAt(i) != 13)) {
            UniCodestring = " Unicode ";
            Countsms = 70;
            if ($('#SndSms_Message').val().length > 70)
                Countsms = 67;

            return;
        }

        i++;
    }
    Countsms = 160;
    UniCodestring = "";
    if ($('#SndSms_Message').val().length > 160)
        Countsms = 153;

}
var Countsms = 160;
var UniCodestring = "";
var CounterSmsLen = 0;
var Two = "|^€{}[]~";





function GetCountSms() {




document.getElementById('SndSms_Message').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        var target = e.SndSms_Message,
            position = SndSms_Message.selectionStart;





    ConvertGreek();
    CounterSmsLen = $('#SndSms_Message').val().length;
    GetAlhpa($('#SndSms_Message').val());

    var i = 0;
    while (i < String(Two).length) {
        var oldindex = -1;
        while (String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i)), oldindex) > -1) {
            //if ( String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i))) > -1){
            CounterSmsLen += 1;
            oldindex = String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i)), oldindex) + 1;


            console.log(i);
        }
        i++;

    }


SndSms_Message.selectionEnd = position;    // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
    });




    if ($('#SndSms_Message').val().length == 0)
        CounterSmsLen = 0;

    $('#SndSms_Count').html('  ' + CounterSmsLen + ' Characters' + UniCodestring + ' <br /> ' + Math.ceil(CounterSmsLen / Countsms) + '  Sms');
countsmsnumber=Math.ceil(CounterSmsLen / Countsms);
}
var greekchar = "ΑΒΕΖΗΙΚΜΝΟΡΤΥΧ";
var englishchar = "ABEZHIKMNOPTYX";
function ConvertGreek() {
    var str = $('#SndSms_Message').val();

    var i = 0;
    while (i < String(greekchar).length) {
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(String(greekchar).charAt(i), 'g'), String(englishchar).charAt(i));

        i++;
    }
    $('#SndSms_Message').val(str);
```

P.S.
If i paste the number into the text box it will count it correct but if i paste character it wont count them..

Comment: You might want to handle the `paste` event as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste

Comment: try using document.getElementById('SndSms_Message').addEventListener('input propertychange', function (e) {}

Comment: @NomiAli i tried what you have said and its wont work (even if i type a letter its not working any more)

Comment: @Azrahedour The below answer will work. this was in jquery it wouldn't work. refer below answer I've give.

Comment: @NomiAli any way you can help me in this?

Comment: @Azrahedour it should work on every machine as it is simple javascript, unless javascript is enable in each browser you use.

Answer (score 0):

You need keyup change event in order to handle paste event.

```
document.getElementById('SndSms_Message').addEventListener("keyup", function() {
   //your code here
});
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/p62q0vc0/)

Comment: the paste is working on some computers and on some its not working, also the way its counting the character its not counting the first character. Can you guide me on this?